# Black Lion Scrap drop chance from Black Lion Chest?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm curious to know what the drop rate of [Black Lion Ticket Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Claim_Ticket_Scrap) from the [Black Lion Chest](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest).

If I was to open 100 [BLC](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest)'s how many scraps should I expect to receive?

It's linked in the ['Common drops' section of the wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest#Common_drops).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a more or less hidden wiki article on the [Black Lion Chest Drop rates](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest/Drop_rate), which is a user-curated list of drops, totalling 886 chests. Due to changes in the drop chances with patches, I would not trust on the reliability of this method.

A better way to check current droprates is to look on the Guild Wars 2 subreddit for posts of people mass-opening chests. According the [most recent one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/31159t/results_of_opening_250_black_lion_chest_after_the/) documented on the Guild Wars 2 subreddit, there was an increase in drop chance after the then (April 1st, 2015) most recent patch.

Opening a total of 350 chests yielded 132 scraps and 7 full tickets, for an effective total of 202 scraps. This would place the effective droprate at around **57.7±4.1%**. The error estimates here assumes  that 350 is a big enough sample size for a Gaussian distribution (square root error).